# How can I force a USB device driver to call a specific HCI controller driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have looked into couple USB device driver code looks like they have to associates with PCI device(s) and when usb_submit_urb() is called in USB device driver, the urb structure has already been associated with specific HCI driver, then when usb_submit_urb() calls usb_hcd_submit_urb (), usb_hcd_submit_urb() will fetch hcd from the parameter urb then calls urb->enqueue() which maps to the specific HCI driver.

```
int usb_hcd_submit_urb (struct urb *urb, gfp_t mem_flags)
{
    int         status;
    struct usb_hcd      *hcd = bus_to_hcd(urb->dev->bus);

    ......
    ......
        if (likely(status == 0)) {
            status = hcd->driver->urb_enqueue(hcd, urb, mem_flags);
```

In my case I need to write a USB HCI driver that talks to a hardware which needs to be hidden from USB device driver, so I cannot change USB device driver to search for PCI ids for the hardware... In this case is there any way to force a specific device driver to associate with the USB HCI driver?

Update:

I have created two diagrams based on the discussion.

Diagram #1 shows the current USB model in kernel, I see from 'lspci' output that xHCI is the only host controller driver that is being used in my system.

Diagram #2 is a proposed design. While still allows NCM CDC device driver to work as a driver for current devices listed in its PCI tables, I would like to register my customized HCI with USB core for NCM CDC device driver. The customized HCI talks to customized hardware driver which hides the customized hardware info from user space (meaning there is no PCI probe).

My customized HCI needs to parse URB messages passed down from USB core and map them to corresponding APIs provided by customized hardware driver.

The problems I am having is that it looks like xHCI is by default used by all USB device drivers, I am not sure how can I tell USB core to use my customized HCI at all... even if I maybe able to hardcode USB core to force all traffics from NCM CDC USB device driver to customized HCI,  because I won't be able to provide PCI productID/vendorID to NCM CDC device driver, how can I trigger NCM CDC device driver's probe() function to start at all?

```
Diagram #1 (Current kernel USB model):
  -----------------           ------------------           -------------------             -------------------
  |    NCM CDC    |  <---->   |    USB Core    |   <---->  |       xHCI      |    <---->   |   USB devices   |
  -----------------           ------------------           -------------------             -------------------





Diagram #2 (proposed design):
  -----------------           ------------------           -----------------------------             --------------------------------            --------------------
  |    NCM CDC    |  <---->   |    USB Core    |   <----->  |       Customized HCI      |    <---->  |   Customized Hardware driver |    <---->  |   Customized HW  |
  -----------------           ------------------      |     -----------------------------            --------------------------------            --------------------
                                                      |
                                                      |
                                                      |
                                                      |    -------------------             -------------------
                                                      |--->|       xHCI      |    <---->   |   USB devices   |
                                                           -------------------             -------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly your needs: you need to write a HCI driver which will be working outside of standard USB stack in Linux? So you don't want to register your HCI in Linux usb-core? If yes - just write HCI driver and don't register his API into usb-core. AFAIK which USB HCI driver (and HCI HW) is used only depends on the physical USB port you connected. So if you have system with more than one USB HCI then you can select HCI just by plugging USB device to given physical port. As I remember in USB 2.0 (ehci + companion controller) there was possibility to assign some USB port to either ehci or uhci/ohci (with some kind of mux) but now with xhci - I don't think it is possible. Mainly because xhci doesn't need any companion controller.

Comment: I actually need to utilize USB core because I want some existing USB device driver to forward their traffics to my HCI driver.  I did hear something about USB 2.0 you mentioned recently, in my case I am more like writing a USB/IP VHCI on client side (vhci_hcd.c) but would like it to be accessible by USB device driver other than user space program + ioctl()...

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get your point. The question is: you've got some HW with USB device and on this HW you want to write virtual HCI which is USB-over-IP solution? So via IP protocol you want to control your HCI?

Comment: sorry for the confusions, I don't need IP for my HCI driver. What I need to do is to route the traffics from NCM CDC device driver to my HCI class, my HCI class should parse the URB query and call HW driver APIs to provide an emulated output back to NCM CDC device driver. I am not given access to HW driver code. So my HCI class can't actually talk to any hardware directly, and not able to put itself in PCI bus to be detected by NCM CDC driver either...I am thinking worse case I can export my VHCI  symbol and hard code usb_hcd_submit_urb() to point to my HCI via usb_hcd...does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your needs properly. Some detailed picture of your idea would be helpful in this case. If you are trying to use NCM CDC device (eth-over-usb?) then you need physical usb-device and physical usb-host. Keeping in mind that always usb-host is the initiator of any USB communication you could write your own driver instead of NCM CDC or modify this CDC driver and there you can do anything with the requests. Regarding your question - I'm not sure if this is good idea for production software. For testing purposes, debug or some research - maybe, but not for production.

Comment: If you can please draw some picture and specify where are the USB controllers (USB device and/or USB host). Maybe with this picture I would help you.

Comment: thanks for helping out. I have updated the question with some diagrams.. please kindly let me know if you have any idea.yes I am trying to route NCM CDC (eth-over-usb) driver's traffic to the customized HCI.  And looks like only xHCI can actually works as a real host controller driver that talks to USB device drivers on top of USB core (I have checked USB/IP VHCI code, looks like they have to use sysfs from user space to talk to VHCI code instead of creating a  USB device drivers on top of USB core, so it doesn't look easy to just tell any USB device driver to talk to a customized HCI).

Comment: The only idea I've got at the moment is to modify NCM CDC driver and introduce there some kind of bridge/connection with your vhci driver. Your vhci could fetch some data from NCM CDC driver and return some response back to NCM CDC. However I'm not sure if this is ok for you.

Comment: Sure that sounds very reasonable for what I need.  I am thinking of using EXPORT_SYMBOL() to expose APIS inside NCM CDC driver to vhci host driver (and any other kernel modules) and vice verse. What might be a better way to do it instead?  And also how can I avoid breaking the path for existing PCI devices listed in NCM CDC device driver ?  Of course I still want those normal devices to go though path of [NCM CDC] -> [USB core] -> [xHCI]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your second question right. Are you asking for that how to add support for your USB device keeping support for already supported devices in NCM CDC? Or in other words - how to distinct maintenance of your USB device from already supported ones?

Comment: I assume that you know VendorID and ProductID of your USB device. You may check those IDs in NCM CDC driver and route the communication to your vHCI.